# Make the right rule for urlManager Yii

Tags: php, yii, routes

Good time. There was a question on setting rules for urlManager. Need to do to be able to pass id defaultController controller. For example, I defaultController = "default" and I need to pass it the parameter, ie whatever you type http://site.ru/abc to cause the controller default, action = index and there passed the id parameter with a value of abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

I suppose you use Apache: go to httpd.conf then change Document Root to your Yii project:

```
 Document Root ".../www/your_yii_project"
```

Configuration routes by editing main.php in config folder: when you passed value for the id then actionIndex() in SiteController will be called.

```
.......
    'urlManager' => array(
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'caseSensitive' => false,
                 'rules' => array(
                        ........
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<id:\w+>' => 'site/index'
                        .....
                    )

        ),
.....
```

My SiteController like:

```
class SiteController extends CController
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        var_dump($_GET);
    }

}
```

The final thing you should see this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/ to hide index.php in your URL. That's it. Here is my result:

```
http://localhost:81/abc
```

**it return:**
array (size=1)
  'id' => string 'abc' (length=3)